# The integral of ln(sigmoid function)

Tags: calculus

Pretty much the title. The sigmoid function in the form $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$ and i want to find $\int \ln(\sigma(x)) dx$ I've had a crack at it and cant figure it out for the life of me. My most pertinent questions are: what is its closed-form solution? does a closed-form solution even exist? any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the substitution $u = e^{-x}$ then you get

$$\int \ln \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}\right) dx = \int \frac{\ln(1 + u)}{u} du$$

which in turn can be transformed into something resembling the [dilogarithm function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html), giving the final result that the integral is equal to $-\mathrm{Li}_2(-e^{-x})$.